# How to display alert based on query results from controller?

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am calling a method in a controller via ajax from a view. This method runs a query to see if a value passed through the ajax to the method is located in the database. The result I need is to display an alert to the user if the value was found. How would I do this?

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ScannerProcess(string jobnumber, string programname, string description)
{
    try
    {
        var _process = new ScannerProcess();
        _process.JobNumberExist(jobnumber);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Method:

```
public void JobNumberExist(string jobnumber)
{
    using (var ctx = new Scanner())
    {
        bool results = false;

        var sql = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<tScanner>(@"SELECT * FROM  tScanner
                            WHERE  (JobNumber = @jobnumber)"
            , new SqlParameter("@jobnumber", jobnumber)).ToList();

        if (sql.Count > 0)
        {
            //Display alert on view that job number was found
        }
    }
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ScannerProcess",
    data: { programname: $('#programName').val(), jobnumber: $('#jobNumber').val(), description: $('#description').val() }
})
.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

})
.always(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From controller action return JsonResult like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ScannerProcess(string jobnumber, string programname, string description)
{
    try
    {
        var _process = new ScannerProcess();
        var foundNumber = _process.JobNumberExist(jobnumber);
        // If you don't want to add status message in Action as its "view" specific, you can add message based on combination of DidSucceed and foundNumber property check in javascript as shown below.
        var message = foundNumber ? "Number Found Successfully" : "Number not found";
        return Json(new { DidSucceed = true, status = "success", message = message, foundNumber = foundNumber }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
        // throw; // Since this action is invoked via AJAX, I would say throwing exceptions is not a good practice.
        return Json(new { DidSucceed = false, status = "error", message = "Unknown Exception Occured." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Modify signature of JobNumberExist method (just a side note, its bad practice to run queries like this. Please refer DBContext on how to execute queries) to return true or false

```
public **bool** JobNumberExist(string jobnumber)
{
    using (var ctx = new Scanner())
    {
        bool results = false;

        var sql = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<tScanner>(@"SELECT * FROM  tScanner
                            WHERE  (JobNumber = @jobnumber)"
            , new SqlParameter("@jobnumber", jobnumber)).ToList();

        return sql.Count > 0 ;
    }
}
```

and from javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ScannerProcess",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { programname: $('#programName').val(), jobnumber: $('#jobNumber').val(), description: $('#description').val() }
})
.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if ($.isPlainObject(data) && !data.DidSucceed) {
        // Display error message in your respective DIV
    }
    else {
        if (data.foundNumber === true) {
           // Display your own success message or display data.message which is added in MVC action   
        }
        else { 
           // Display your own error message or display data.message which is added in MVC action
        }
    }
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

})
.always(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

});
```